# How to change the topology in the selected area?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I would like to model such a cube. In 3dmax there is a function that changes the topology of the object in the selected area. How to do this in blender?

Comment: what do you mean by changing topology? do you mean something like a brush that will create some pattern or do you mean something like knife tool where you can cut the topology?